# Best settings to Shoot best dynamic range - Shoots like the human eye sees the details and the contrast between the bright light and the outside

Tags: image-quality, light, hdr, dynamic-range

I want to shoot a photography but the image looks too bright or too dark.

TOO BRIGHT HERE
[image]

TOO DARK HERE
[image]

Here I made some editing (I combined these two photo into one ) to show how it seen through the human eye
[image]

Are there some settings to shoots like the human eye sees the details and the contrast between the bright light and the outside ?

Comment: Often time when shooting a high-contrast scene, you will have to choose which "side" is more important to you to preserve in the capture, then adjust it in post to present the way you feel best reflects your vision. I tend to aim high but with the caveat that i'm ok with losing 1-3% of the image to blown out highlights. Often i find that trying to preserve every little highlight makes the rest of the image much noisier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no camera which can manage such high dynamic range (as on your photos). The best you can do is to use technique, named [exposure bracketing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bracketing). This will result several images which capture different lightness. Then merging them in post and you will get so named HDR images.

Comment: HDR (High Dynamic Range) processing uses the exposure stack to produce a wide dynamic range image. There are various programs out there than can do HDR. Look for something that can do *fusion*, like Enfuse which is part of the Hugin package. Another HDR technique is *tone mapping* which can give unrealistic look to the images (some like tone mapping because the result is "artsy").

Comment: HDR does *not* produce a wide dynamic range image. It produces a low dynamic range image that is displayable on our limited dynamic range display mediums (monitors, printing paper, etc.) that contains details from a wider dynamic range in the original scene. HDR imaging is for fitting a high dynamic range *scene* into a low dynamic range *display medium*, just as Ansel Adams' *Zone System* was for negatives that could capture more dynamic range than printing papers could display.